# A YUM/DNF repository defined multiple times (In-place upgrade from CentOS 7 to AlmaLinux 8)

Tags: linux, centos, linux-kernel, upgrade, alma-linux

Does anyone knows how to solve this issue? Keep getting this error when executing a leapp upgrade.

[image: upgrade inhibited]

[image: /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.txt]

[image: yum.repos]

[image: CentOS.Base.repo]

Comment: please don't post pictures of text from terminals and text files. Instead, copy and paste the text, and use the "code formatting" button on it, labeled `{}`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: _"repository defined multiple times"_ seems clear enough - have you tried to search and delete multiple references?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had just upgraded MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0 in preparation for the upgrade and the issue was between those two repos.

```
rm /etc/yum.repos.d/Mysql57.repo
```

...let the upgrade run, but then the server wouldn't boot.

Comment: I don’t understand.  Are you offering this *as a solution* to the problem?   Or are you saying only that you got the same error message, and then providing some information you discovered about what happened to you at the time?   (“the  server wouldn’t boot” doesn’t sound like a happy ending.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).